# Creating functions that have side effects (in-place) from prototype functions that don't

Tags: javascript

I want to wrap some prototype functionality without using return values.

The following code returns a sorted list in modern browser developer consoles:

```
Array.prototype.sor = function() {
  Array.prototype.sort.apply(this);
};
var t = [2,3,1]
t.sor()
t
```

As does the variation below:

```
sor = function(l) {
  Array.prototype.sort.apply(l);
};
var t = [2,3,1]
sor(t)
t
```

Is it also possible to cause in-place effects for the array (as `sor` has) using non-in-place prototype functions that return their result, such as `join` or, for Strings, `trim` or `replace`?

For example, like this:

```
String.prototype.tri = function() {
  String.prototype.trim.apply(this);
};
var t = " 123"
t.tri()
t
```

Which would ideally return `"123"` in a browser console (the new value for `t`). It does not, since `String.prototype.trim` returns a value that is never picked up. But, of course, I can not simply set `this` to the trimmed string:

```
  this = String.prototype.trim.apply(this);
```

Comment: Wait. You mean your goal is to replace standard functions with functions not returning anything ? Why ? What would that mean for functions not changing their receiver like `join` ?

Comment: You mean that when you use `var ar = [1,2]; ar.join(',');`, `ar` should become a String?

Comment: `"1,2"`, to be exact, yes.  
@DenysSéguret: `sor` does not return anything either. `Array.prototype.sort` does return the array, but has already sorted it in-place, according to the MDN and my test, and so has `sor`.  (how do I do newlines in comments?) Good point though, doing `join` in-place would change the type and be dangerous. I will not do that.

Comment: There's no way to mutate an array to a string. This question doesn't seem to make sense in JavaScript.

Comment: It would be impossible? Good to know! However, I just want to do things like `replace`.

Comment: can you provide sample what you want?

Comment: Yes! In a comment or question edit?

Comment: The only way I can think of (not ideal), is to use the window context and use the name of the variable as a parameter: http://jsfiddle.net/f4a2b2g0/ Or doing it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/h5n7m21k/

Comment: Thank you! Is this considered dangerous or "just" ugly? You can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to use the context, and refer to your variable by using bracket notation `context['nameOfVar']`.

That can be done because a JS variable is nothing but an Object property (The Object being the scope).

If you variables are always declared in the global scope, you could do `window['myVar']`, but to make sure it applies at any scope, it would be better to use `this['myVar']`.

I'm not sure if it is *dangerous* or not, I just find it *hacky*. If anyone knows, tell us! :)

```js
var joinMe = function(separator, prop) {
  this[prop] = this[prop].join(separator);
};

t = [2,3,1];

joinMe(',', 't');

document.body.innerHTML = t; // "2,3,1"
```